# Theoretical problems with modeling auction systems

Tags: regression, predictive-models, logistic

Lets say that we have an online auction where various known sellers and known buyers exchange product X. A seller will post product X and each seller will then bid in accordance with X and if they want it. The highest bidder would win X. Think of something like Ebay, though the auction I'm thinking of has a set number of *known* buyers and *known* sellers, and occurs in a must faster time period (1-2 minutes).

Obviously there is a lot of uncertainty which cannot be accounted for in a model that tries to predict the probability of winning as a buyer in such a scenario. However, I was wondering what were some of the *theoretical* and *practical* limitations in trying to use statistical models to predict outcomes in a online auction system as described above.

EDIT: I'm specifically thinking of a model which is trying to predict the likelihood of winning based on our bid as a buyer.

Comment: Do you have access to previous auction results for product X ?

Comment: Yes, I have access to previous auction bid and results for product X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to take a look at [An Introduction to the Structural Econometrics of Auction Data by Harry J. Paarsch and Han Hong](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=10713) (link to book publisher) and at [Structural Econometric Methods in Auctions: A Guide to the Literature by Hickman et al.](http://home.uchicago.edu/~hickmanbr/uploads/Auction_Econometrics_Survey.pdf) (working paper version). Depending on the details of the auction and what data you observe, this book and paper should get you pretty far.

Comment: Hi Dimitriy, If you could add full citations, I think that would be helpful. Also, the second looks like a google link to the document of interest rather than the direct link to the PDF. Cheers. :)

Comment: Fixed! I was posting from a phone earlier, which makes formatting difficult.